# how to display parameter values instead of question marks in log file

Tags: file, logging, display

How to display parameter values instead of question marks in log file as below..

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
   WHEN (a.CNT = 0 AND b.cnt = 0) THEN 'N'
   ELSE  CASE  WHEN a.CNT = b.CNT THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N' END 
   END      AS Final_Status
FROM
  (SELECT NVL(COUNT(*),1) CNT
  FROM FPC_INFO
  WHERE BILL_MONTH_DT = ?
  AND CUST_TYPE_NM    = UPPER(?)
  AND FINALIZED_USER IS NOT NULL
  ) a,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) CNT
  FROM FPC_INFO
  WHERE BILL_MONTH_DT = ?
  AND CUST_TYPE_NM    = UPPER(?)
  ) b
```

My expectation is like:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
   WHEN (a.CNT = 0 AND b.cnt = 0) THEN 'N'
   ELSE  CASE  WHEN a.CNT = b.CNT THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N' END 
   END      AS Final_Status
FROM
  (SELECT NVL(COUNT(*),1) CNT
  FROM FPC_INFO
  WHERE BILL_MONTH_DT = '01-SEP-2015'
  AND CUST_TYPE_NM    = UPPER('UVERSE')
  AND FINALIZED_USER IS NOT NULL
  ) a,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) CNT
  FROM FPC_INFO
  WHERE BILL_MONTH_DT = '01-SEP-2015'
  AND CUST_TYPE_NM    = UPPER('UVERSE')
  ) b
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry for unformatted code.**

I'm getting log with question marks like below in Log file..

> `SELECT CASE
>              WHEN (a.CNT = 0
>                    AND b.cnt = 0) THEN 'N'
>              ELSE CASE
>                       WHEN a.CNT = b.CNT THEN 'Y'
>                       ELSE 'N'
>                   END
>          END AS Final_Status
>   FROM
>     (SELECT NVL(COUNT(),1) CNT
>      FROM FPC_INFO
>      WHERE BILL_MONTH_DT = ?
>        AND CUST_TYPE_NM = UPPER(?)
>        AND FINALIZED_USER IS NOT NULL) a,
>     (SELECT COUNT() CNT
>      FROM FPC_INFO
>      WHERE BILL_MONTH_DT = ?
>        AND CUST_TYPE_NM = UPPER(?)) b`

But i'm expecting it to print like below with appended values in log file:

> `SELECT CASE
>              WHEN (a.CNT = 0
>                    AND b.cnt = 0) THEN 'N'
>              ELSE CASE
>                       WHEN a.CNT = b.CNT THEN 'Y'
>                       ELSE 'N'
>                   END
>          END AS Final_Status
>   FROM
>     (SELECT NVL(COUNT(),1) CNT
>      FROM FPC_INFO
>      WHERE BILL_MONTH_DT = '01-SEP-2015'
>        AND CUST_TYPE_NM = UPPER('UVERSE')
>        AND FINALIZED_USER IS NOT NULL) a,
>     (SELECT COUNT() CNT
>      FROM FPC_INFO
>      WHERE BILL_MONTH_DT = '01-SEP-2015'
>        AND CUST_TYPE_NM = UPPER('UVERSE')) b`