# SQL Parameterized Query with Names instead of Question Marks

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameterized-query

**Question:**

Is there a way to use names instead of question marks for paramaterized queries? If so, can anyone suggest some material that explains how to do this/the syntax?

**A bit more detail:**

For example, if I have something like:

```
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES(?)
```

Is it possible to have something like this instead that does the exact same thing as the question mark:

```
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES("prices")
```

I tried checking to see if it would work myself before posting the question, but it didn't work. So, I thought I'd ask if it was possible.

I feel like if you have a really long query with, let's say 20 parameters, you don't want to have to count question marks to make sure you have enough parameters whenever you change something. Also, I think it might make the code a bit more readable (especially if you have a lot of parameters to keep track of).

I'm rather new to sql, so I am not sure if it makes much of a difference (for this question) if I add that I'm using postgresql.

**Note:**

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070059/how-to-display-parameter-values-instead-of-question-marks-in-log-file), but it didn't have an answer that was helpful

Comment: Can you please describe the context? What will evaluate the parametrized SQL statement? Which API are you considering?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to encapsulate the big query in a [**function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html), where you can use parameter names.
One example (out of many):

- [PostgreSQL parameterized Order By / Limit in table function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function/8146245#8146245)

You can even set default values and call the function with named parameters, etc.:

- [Functions with variable number of input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782199/functions-with-variable-number-of-input-parameters/16789179#16789179)